# When a client connects using an already-connected keys, it is the older client that is disconnected, rather than the newer being dissmissed

Tags: openvpn, keys

For administrative purposes some people from an administrative team share the same key to a server and it happens sometimes that one of them is already connected to the server when another is also trying to connect. So when an other team member tries to connect it leads to periods of disconnections / connections for both of them. How can the disconnection of the first client be avoided?
When the second one tries to connect it would be desirable to receive a message that a client with the same key is logged in so its access is discarded.

I don't want to have duplicate certification enabled.
We didn't created multiple keys for each team member as the involvement of other team members occured/occures in an ad hoc way and they would not use the keys regularly they just had to do some fixes, little projects. Also we would like to have just one key for our administrator but sometimes somebody else from our teams also needs to jump in so needs access, this is solved by handing over our keys to the persons who have some work to do on the server. Furthermore our internal policy for the trust of our clients restricts us from creating more keys than one for the administrator and the others for the customers.

Comment: Why they share same key? You cannot identify who kill your environnment if more people share same key. Just generate one key for each person.

Comment: Plus - when someone is fired, you cannot disable vpn access for him/her without regeneration of key for everyone.

Comment: added explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I've read this question a few times, trying to make sure I understand it.  You already know about `--duplicate-cn`, and you don't want to permit that.

It seems to me that what you're **actually** asking is "*how do I set up OpenVPN so that when a second client tries to connect using an already-connected set of keys, it is the **newer** client that is refused, rather than the **older** being disconnected while the newer is allowed in*.

If that's what you want to know, the answer (as far as I know) is **you can't**.  The *reason* for that is that people do get disconnected sessions, and you want them to be able to reconnect the moment their internet access comes back, instead of having to wait - perhaps for an hour or more - for their orphan session to time out and be reaped.

You could recompile OpenVPN yourself, making the change you desire, but I'd advise against it.  Better to use a tool like swatch, to watch your OpenVPN logs in real-time, and when it sees the signatures of a duplicate-based disconnection:

```
Mar 14 08:48:16 rubicon openvpn[17250]: MULTI: new connection by client 'cn.redacted' will cause previous active sessions by this client to be dropped.  Remember to use the --duplicate-cn option if you want multiple clients using the same certificate or username to concurrently connect.
```

it should flag you as network admin, so that you can raise this with the people concerned.